# Logcat continously shows messages

Tags: android, logcat

I don't know what's wrong. My logcat has been troubling me for two days. When device is connected to test, the logcat continuously gives messages though I don't run my app. If I run my app, I am unable to find my app logs in such a huge amount of data. Can someone suggest me to avoid this and so that I can only view my application's logs? Below is the logcat's flow which continously flows. I am testing with htc.

```
04-09 09:27:10.007: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 128K, 43% free 3530K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 142ms
04-09 09:27:10.027: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:10.027: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:10    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  1304    http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:10.037: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:10.037: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:10.057: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:10.238: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 50K, 43% free 3522K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 158ms
04-09 09:27:10.408: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 43% free 3537K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 140ms
04-09 09:27:10.408: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:10.468: D/com.fd.httpd(843): sdcard phone type != 1
04-09 09:27:10.478: D/com.fd.httpd(843): emmc phone type != 1
04-09 09:27:10.498: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479830502--enter query.
04-09 09:27:10.558: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:10    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    GET /info/  -   200 1471    0   513 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:10.568: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:10.568: I/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "pragma" is discouraged as a future versions of the Restlet API will directly support it.
04-09 09:27:10.578: W/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "cache-control" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
04-09 09:27:10.578: W/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "expires" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
04-09 09:27:10.578: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:10.578: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:10.598: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479830607--leave query.
04-09 09:27:10.598: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:10.608: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:10.688: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:10    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  252 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:10.688: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:10.688: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:10.698: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:10.838: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 156K, 43% free 3525K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 124ms
04-09 09:27:10.848: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:10.898: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479830906--enter query.
04-09 09:27:10.958: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479830966--leave query.
04-09 09:27:10.958: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:10.958: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:11.048: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:11    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  171 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:11.048: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:11.048: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:11.058: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:11.199: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 93K, 43% free 3530K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 133ms
04-09 09:27:11.209: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:11.249: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479831256--enter query.
04-09 09:27:11.319: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479831324--leave query.
04-09 09:27:11.319: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:11.319: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:11.349: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:11    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  119 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:11.349: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:11.349: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:11.359: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:11.519: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 103K, 43% free 3522K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 147ms
04-09 09:27:11.539: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:11.569: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479831577--enter query.
04-09 09:27:11.649: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479831651--leave query.
04-09 09:27:11.649: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:11.649: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:11.799: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 71K, 43% free 3529K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 139ms
04-09 09:27:11.809: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:11    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  261 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:11.819: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:11.829: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:11.839: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:11.849: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:11.989: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 45K, 43% free 3526K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 123ms
04-09 09:27:12.119: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 43% free 3525K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 115ms
04-09 09:27:12.129: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:12.180: D/com.fd.httpd(843): sdcard phone type != 1
04-09 09:27:12.190: D/com.fd.httpd(843): emmc phone type != 1
04-09 09:27:12.210: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479832225--enter query.
04-09 09:27:12.260: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:12    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    GET /info/  -   200 1471    0   429 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:12.260: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:12.270: I/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "pragma" is discouraged as a future versions of the Restlet API will directly support it.
04-09 09:27:12.270: W/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "cache-control" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
04-09 09:27:12.270: W/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "expires" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
04-09 09:27:12.270: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:12.280: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:12.430: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479832442--leave query.
04-09 09:27:12.430: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:12.430: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:12.560: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:12    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  403 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:12.570: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:12.570: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:12.580: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:12.750: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 152K, 43% free 3535K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 159ms
04-09 09:27:12.770: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:12.810: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479832825--enter query.
04-09 09:27:12.940: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479832950--leave query.
04-09 09:27:12.940: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:12.940: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:13.070: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:13    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  289 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:13.080: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:13.080: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:13.090: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:13.261: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 97K, 43% free 3533K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 163ms
04-09 09:27:13.271: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:13.441: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 34K, 43% free 3525K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 127ms
04-09 09:27:13.461: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:13.481: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479833498--enter query.
04-09 09:27:13.631: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 63K, 43% free 3536K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 125ms
04-09 09:27:13.681: D/com.fd.httpd(843): sdcard phone type != 1
04-09 09:27:13.691: D/com.fd.httpd(843): emmc phone type != 1
04-09 09:27:13.731: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479833746--leave query.
04-09 09:27:13.731: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:13.731: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:13.751: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:13    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  461 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:13.771: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:13.771: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:13.791: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:13.791: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:13    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    GET /info/  -   200 1471    0   293 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:13.791: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:13.801: I/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "pragma" is discouraged as a future versions of the Restlet API will directly support it.
04-09 09:27:13.801: W/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "cache-control" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
04-09 09:27:13.941: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 70K, 43% free 3541K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 134ms
04-09 09:27:13.941: W/Server(843): Addition of the standard header "expires" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
04-09 09:27:13.941: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:13.961: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:13.961: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:14.011: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834023--enter query.
04-09 09:27:14.081: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834094--leave query.
04-09 09:27:14.081: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:14.081: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:14.101: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834113--leave applyBatch.
04-09 09:27:14.111: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:14    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  125 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:14.121: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:14.121: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:14.131: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:14.262: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 140K, 43% free 3512K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 119ms
04-09 09:27:14.272: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:14.332: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834330--enter query.
04-09 09:27:14.392: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834406--leave query.
04-09 09:27:14.392: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:14.392: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:14.422: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:14    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  115 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:14.422: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:14.422: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:14.432: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:14.562: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 95K, 43% free 3517K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 119ms
04-09 09:27:14.572: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:14.632: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834644--enter query.
04-09 09:27:14.682: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834693--enter applyBatch.
04-09 09:27:14.712: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834728--leave query.
04-09 09:27:14.722: I/com.fd.httpd(843): sum size = 0
04-09 09:27:14.722: I/com.fd.httpd(843): Thread stateRUNNABLE
04-09 09:27:14.732: I/LogService(843): 2013-04-09   09:27:14    127.0.0.1   -   127.0.0.1   8182    POST    /library/do/summary -   200 64  53  149 http://null -   -
04-09 09:27:14.742: D/nicolas(843): HttpServerHelper commit
04-09 09:27:14.752: D/nicolas(843): sendResponse 1
04-09 09:27:14.762: D/nicolas(843): writeResponseBody
04-09 09:27:14.912: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 103K, 43% free 3517K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 144ms
04-09 09:27:14.932: I/LogFilter(843): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
04-09 09:27:14.962: I/com.fd.httpd(843): 1365479834978--enter query.
04-09 09:27:15.112: D/dalvikvm(843): GC_EXPLICIT freed 68K, 43% free 3523K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 136ms
```

Comment: You mean verbose, Error like that? Because I have already tried those. No luck.

Comment: There are different ways to isolate what your app's output. How are you viewing the logcat? Through Eclipse, or the command line? If command line, then what OS?

Answer (score 3):

This method is to view only specific logs,not to avoid unwanted logs coming in logcat.

> adb shell logcat -s D/nicolas

or

> adb shell logcat | grep D/nicolas

for example you only want to view log tagged "nicolas"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this answer. Can you give more details than this?

Comment: Sorry, it might be a noob question, but where to use these commands and how to use?

Comment: These commands are for viewing logcat from the command line. The second one is a pretty good suggestion as long as all your output has some common word (like if you make all your tags the same).

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it wrong, buddy.

Logcat takes down everything happened in your android phone, if you choose "verbose" or "debug" level.
And it seems that you've chosen "debug".

You can try to turn "debug" down to "warn" or "error", those messages which seems useless to you will disappear and won't bother you anymore.

However, I do NOT support you to do so because it will give you a whole look of your phone status, and you'll find it really useful in your later development!

Hope that my answer can help you solve your problem! ^_^

Comment: +1 and thanks for your answer. Now a big question is which answer should be accepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, when looking at the logcat tab in DDMS, there should be a 'Saved Filters' window just to the left of the actual logcat output. The filter is probably the way that you want to see just your messages (the ones you output, and also some system ones generated by your app), so you just need to get one that works.

For me, a session filter is usually automatically created, so whatever program I'm running gets filtered. Check for your program under 'All messages' and click on it. Here's a picture of what it looks like for me:

[image: automatic session filter]

If the session filter is not automatically created, then just make one. Click on the green plus sign, and put your app name into the 'by Application Name' text box.

Comment: +1 and thanks for your answer. Now a big question is which answer should be accepted ;)